# How to set the same color of gradient in joyploy plot fill？

Tags: python, fill, colormap

[target results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP2fa.jpg)

As shown in the picture above, I want to reproduce a similar effect in the picture. The fill color of each plot is the same colormap that gradients from blue to red.

Attached is my code and data

data:[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10AQlMrzkpeYBlhcYqFUxxtR3qVnMqLob/view?usp=drive_link)

However, when I pass in a colormap, all the effects are as follows.

The fill of each line is not the same

How can I modify it to achieve the desired result?

[Current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QszIK.png)

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import joypy
import matplotlib as mpl   
import cmaps
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap 


da = xr.open_dataset(r'J:\code\sst.mnmean.nc').sortby('lat').sel(time=slice('1982', '2021'))


sst_1991_2020 = da.sel(time=slice('1991', '2020')).sst.mean(['time'])
sst_difference = (da.sst-sst_1991_2020).mean(['lon','lat'])

df = sst_difference.to_dataframe().reset_index()



df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['year'] = df['time'].dt.year
labels = df['year']

years = np.arange(df['time'].dt.year.min(), df['time'].dt.year.max() + 1, 5)




norm =  mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-1, vmax=1)   
                                         
cmap =   cmaps.BlueWhiteOrangeRed 
                                       
newcolors=cmap(np.linspace(0,1,12))
                               
newcmap=ListedColormap(newcolors[::1])  


fig,ax = joypy.joyplot(df, 
              by="year", 
              column="sst", 
              range_style='all', 
              linecolor = "white",
              grid="y",
              # ylim='owd',
              # fill=False,
              linewidth=1,
              # sharey=True,
              tails = 0.2, 
              legend=True, 
              # fade=True, 
              overlap=2.5,
              x_range=(-1.5,1.5),
              background='w' ,
              figsize=(6, 10),
              alpha=0.6,
            colormap=newcmap,
            
            title="Global monthly sst  1981-2020 \n(°C above 1991-2020 average)",
            kind="kde", 
            bins=20)
```